# Insert formula in cell using VBA issue

Tags: vba, excel

i am having issues inserting the below formula in a cell. I doubled the " already. Any idea what i am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot

```
Sub insert_formulas()

Worksheets("Parsing").Range("H2").Formula = "=IF(E2=""New"";OFFSET(H2,-1;0)-H2;""N/A"")"


End Sub
```

Replaced it for: (but still error 400)

```
Sub insert_formulas()

Worksheets("Parsing").Range("H2").Formula = "=IF(E2=""New"",OFFSET(H2,-1,0)-H2,""N/A"")"


End Sub
```

Its solved. Thanks - the above is correct.

Comment: You need to use commas, not semicolons for the IF.

Comment: Does inserting the formula directly (without macro) in the cell (of course with single ") works?

Comment: Hello, yes it works just fine without VBA. Already replaced with comas just have error 400 still :/

Comment: Apologies. It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The VBA statement shown in your post (see the one marked with "...the above is correct"):

```
Worksheets("Parsing").Range("H2").Formula = "=IF(E2=""New"",OFFSET(H2,-1;0)-H2,""N/A"")"
```

contains error in OFFSET() Function: it should be corrected as following:

```
Worksheets("Parsing").Range("H2").Formula = "=IF(E2=""New"",OFFSET(H2,-1,0)-H2,""N/A"")"
```

Best regards,

Comment: Nice catch! Good eye.

Comment: Yeah, i realized that after some time, need new glasses! :)